# Trouble with my Query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, join

I have made a simple database application however I am having trouble adding in one final Column. The amount column needs to be populated with the Yearly Premium from the PRODUCTS table and then divided by either 1, 12 or 26 depending on if it is payed Yearly(1), Monthly(12), or Fortnightly(26).

I assume I need to join the SALES and PRODUCTS tables using ProductID but cannot figure out how to populate the amount column depending on how they pay (F / M / Y).

Below is the two screen shots of each table in the program, and the code I am using to populate the Main Sales form at the moment.

[image: Sales Screen where amount needs to be calculated.]

[image: The Yearly premium needs to come from here]

```
private void DisplaySales()
    {
        string selectQuery;
        selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Sales";
        List<Sale> saleList = new List<Sale>();
        try
        {
            // Automatically  open and close the connection
            using (var conn = ConnectionManager.DatabaseConnection())
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conn))
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    //Define the list items
                    var sale = new Sale(
                        int.Parse(rdr["SaleID"].ToString()),
                        int.Parse(rdr["CustomerID"].ToString()),
                        int.Parse(rdr["ProductID"].ToString()),
                        rdr["Payable"].ToString(),
                        DateTime.Parse(rdr["StartDAte"].ToString()));

                    saleList.Add(sale);
                }
                dgvSales.DataSource = saleList;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unsuccessful" + ex);
        }
    }
```

Thank you heaps for any help regarding my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about the join.

```
selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Sales AS Sal INNER JOIN Product AS Pro ON Sal.ProductID = Pro.ProductID
```

Then have a statement that does the logic when you get the results in the while loop.

```
int amount;
switch(rdr["Payable"].ToString()) {
    case "M": amount =         rdr["YearlyPremium"] / 12
    break;
    case "F": amount =     rdr["YearlyPremium"] / 26
    break;
    default: amount =    rdr["YearlyPremium"];
    break;
```

}

Then add amount to the sale object and pass it into the Sale constructor.
You could create your own enum or dictionary to avoid the switch statement. However I would suggest inserting the correct amount when the sale is inserted. Cheers

Make sure your Sale class has this

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This makes total sense. I have tried to implement your solution and am getting this error now. not sure why I am turning it into an INT and I made a new class to have amount in it. https://i.imgur.com/RjJBldq.png

This is how I implemented your code.
https://pastebin.com/xCrWLuq7

I have a feeling this error is caused because it can only read from left to right once or something.

Comment: If you are talking about reading columns left to right, I don't think that would be it. Maybe there is something going on with the data type of the rdr columns. I'd assume INT and varchar columns coming from the database are automatically int and string types

Comment: fuck man. Thanks I actually figured out that I need to use decimal about 2 minutes prior to you typing this comment. It has been a while since I picked up this project and am very rusty. Got it all working now cheers!